# why the file 'application.properties' can not be added correctly to Class for springboot3

Tags: java, spring-boot

application.properties's setting following:

```
user.name=bob
user.age=17
```

here is my User class and annotations:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
@Component
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

here is my application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Boot3Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       var ioc= SpringApplication.run(Boot3Demo1Application.class, args);
        User bean = ioc.getBean(User.class);
        System.out.println(bean);


    }

}
```

here is consle's log:

User{name='inf', age=17}

i am confused that the age is correct but name not.(its the first time i use it)

①i check these files are in correct path.
②if i change the filed 'age' in properties,it could be updated .but if i change 'user.name' ,it still print 'inf'.

Comment: Do you have a local configuration applied for your project?

Something along the lines of config/application-default?

Comment: `user.name` is a Java System variable which will take precedence over your `user.name` in your properties file.

Comment: there is no default value  for project,it is a simple project .
this time i change the class user:
i change the field 'user.name' to 'user.uname' for User and 'application.properties' ,but the consle still print `User{name='inf', age=30}`.

Comment: i forgot to change the method 'setName' to 'setUname' and method 'toString', after updated these details,i found it could print result expected.thank you everyone.I guess user.name may be a system variable because my labtop's user is 'inf'.